# Exclusion of member group in Access Control Policy in Websphere Commerce

Tags: access-control, websphere-commerce, wcs

Access Control tuple is generally defined as

```
AccessControlPolicy [UserGroup, ActionGroup, ResourceGroup, Relationship]
```

If a particular user exists in the UserGroup then according to policy only he/she can access the resource. How can I change the access policy to ***not exist in UserGroup***. I mean resources will only be accessed iff the user does not exit UserGroup. How can it be achieved ?

I am using WCS7

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to do this natively, but you could create a no-op version of a command or action that doesn't do anything and make it the command that executes for users in that group.